# Are there any quantum standards already in development and accessible as draft documents?

Tags: programming, architecture, research

Are there any quantum standards already in development and accessible as draft documents?

Any documents describing standardized way of describing and ensuring common meaning/interoperability, like e.g.:

- device properties and parameters,
- unified access control via API over quantum devices,
- gate naming convention,
- circuit definition portability between various systems,
- quantum security aspects (key management and distribution),
- standardized benchmarks,
- etc.

BTW:

I did a quick check and I see some activity in:

- [ITU](https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/about/groups/Pages/sg17.aspx).
- [CEN-CENELEC Focus Group on Quantum Technologies (FGQT): "Towards European Standards for Quantum Technologies"](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2203/2203.01622.pdf)

This is good article describing a raising need for data organization for quantum devices:
https://jackkrupansky.medium.com/proposal-for-a-quantum-capabilities-label-for-quantum-computers-algorithms-and-applications-430d3b94c4ca